# Can't Fetch Metadata from breeze ,error occurred

Tags: breeze

I am trying to develop some sort of calculator using breeze so that while calculating if user wanna save the datails he/she can save it into database and can display using breeze webapi.

My page with knockout bindings to get data from breeze

```
<div id="calculatorList">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: calculate">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: FirstNumber"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Operator"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: SecondNumber"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Output"></td>
                <td>
                    <button data-bind="click: editCalculate" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button data-bind="click:deleteCalculate" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My DbContext cs file

```
public class ResultDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ResultDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
            Database.SetInitializer<ResultDbContext>(null);
    }
    public DbSet<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[BreezeController]
public class CalculatorController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<ResultDbContext> _cp = new EFContextProvider<ResultDbContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _cp.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable database()
    {
        return _cp.Context.Results;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {

        return _cp.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
}
```

But still I am getting this following error

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Method not found: 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()'.","ExceptionType":"System.MissingMethodException","StackTrace":"   at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.GetMetadataFromDbContext(Object context)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.GetMetadataFromContext(Object context)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.BuildJsonMetadata()\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.Metadata()\r\n   at SpaCalculator.Controllers.CalculatorController.Metadata() in c:\\Users\\arajak\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Calculator\\SpaCalculator\\Controllers\\CalculatorController.cs:line 22\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

Can anyone will say why this error is occurring

Comment: The client side is not the problem. You have a server-error. You're getting "Missing Method Exception" somewhere near `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()` it seems. That's not Breeze code. Time to start debugging the server. Write a test or some kind of code ON THE SERVER that asks the EFContextProvider for metadata. Where is it bombing? Get a stack trace someone can read (not one long line). Then report back and we'll see what's up.

Comment: I have the same issues working with breeze. It is a breeze issue that that the full error message is hidden and you can't even step through in debug mode either. Complete hidden mystery. The author of breeze should fix this as it causes headaches, arguments at the work place once you are forced to use breeze. Too much ambiguity leaves coders in the dark.