# Knockout Bindings using Key value pair

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I am working on knockout with BreezeJs for retrieving and storing data from my local database. The problem I am facing here is the key value binding in  menu. 
What I want to do is to **Display and select the 'Name' attribute from the select menu and store the corresponding 'Id' attribute into my database.**

Till now I am trying like

```
var operators = [
{id: 0, name: 'addition'},
{id: 1, name: 'subtraction'},
{id: 2, name: 'division'},
{id: 3, name: 'multiplication'}
   ];
```

// my html bindings

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.operators , optionText: 'name', optionvalue: 'Id', value: operator"/>
```

// here 'operator' is the colomnName from database in which I am trying to store this thing in integer format.

But as per my code its showing output as

```
[object object]
```

How can I solve this issue for displaying and selecting the 'name' attribute [varchar] from the select menu and store the corresponding 'id' attribute [int] to my database.

//@TSV

The html bindings

```
 <div data-bind="with: jobs">
      <div>
        <label>FirstNumber :</label>
        <input data-bind="value: first_no" />
    </div>

         <div>
        <label>operator :</label>
         <select data-bind="options: $root.operators , optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: $root.operator"/>
    </div>
     <div>
        <label>Second Number:</label>
        <input data-bind="value: second_no" />
    </div><div>
        <label>Result :</label>
        <input data-bind="value: result" />
    </div></div>
```

// these(result,second_no,operator,first_no) are the column names in my database and 'jobs' is an observableArray.

Note : I am using breezeJS to get & store data from database that's why I mentioned a tag of it, though the above problem is of knockout rather than breeze.

Comment: Change `optionText` to `optionsText` and `optionvalue` to `optionsValue`.

Comment: Your first question was about options knockout binding for the select element. And looks like it was solved. Does is right?

Comment: The second question is that you have an array (observable) loaded from database, this array is bound to some controls via knockout, and finally you want entered values to be saved into database. Right? So where is the code responsible for loading data from database and storing them back?

Comment: @TSV binding issue was solved earlier, and if you want you can look at this code but till now I have made few changes so don't go for the variables names but still that code works fine.                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446415/cant-fetch-metadata-from-breeze-error-occurred?noredirect=1#comment45271710_28446415

Comment: I see two problems in your code: first - knockout select options, second - BreezeJs library usage. That's why i'd recommend to split this question. The second one should IMO contain small complete sample, illustrating the problem.

Comment: In case of using "<select>" inside binding loop, probably you should use "value: operator" instead of "value: $root.operator" in order to store id into each object of an array.

Comment: I was looking on the knockout context bindings, so what I tried a little bit modification in code and Voila it worked, here,  <select data-bind="options: $root.operators, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: $data.operator"/>    I just changed $root to $data, And TSV thanks for your precious help and I was gonna ask one more favor frm you that if  you know the perfect example where I can find all the Knockout Context bindings for these variables $parent, $parents, $root, $data, $index, $parentContext, $context, $element. I want the clear picture of it while working.

Comment: You can find it in the Knockout documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: By the way "value: $data.operator" is the same as "value: operator" as I recommended earlier.

Comment: Hey TSV can you check the question I posted,  I am struggling  for answer  but can't find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665589/knockout-custom-html-bindings-for-displaying-some-extra-fields-to-enter-the-rela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for me:

```js
var operators = [
{id: 0, name: 'addition'},
{id: 1, name: 'subtraction'},
{id: 2, name: 'division'},
{id: 3, name: 'multiplication'}
   ];

ko.applyBindings({ operators: operators, operator: ko.observable(2) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: $root.operators, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: 
$root.operator"/>
```

I've patched following issues in your code: inserted comma after "division'}", corrected "optionsText" and "optionsValue" params, optionsValue should be 'id'.

Comment: thanks TSV for answering, Still I am facing one problem that the corresponding 'id' is not at all saved  into database, the only entry in database in operator column is '0' which refers Addition, while I am trying the others 'name' attribute(every time when I am trying to add any row).

Comment: It seems to me that this question was rather related to the knockout options binding than BreezeJs library. I believe, if you ask corresponding questions with clear short clear scenario description and code sample (using BreezeJs client library), you certainly will get the answer.

Comment: Here is nothing new I can show you here, as I am using breeze to extract data from database using breeze controller and store it in some observable which have bindings in html tags.

Comment: As you can check the code I pasted as per your request @TSV